# firefox 26 and webdriver 2.39.0 upgradation is not working

Tags: firefox, selenium

I upgraded firefox to 26 which gave org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException:

Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output: *** LOG addons.manager: Application has been upgraded

then I upgraded the webdriver to 2.39 which supports firefox 26...  but still its not working..
OS is win 7

Exception is:

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:

*** LOG addons.manager: Application has been upgraded

*** LOG addons.xpi: startup

*** LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-local

*** LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share

*** LOG addons.xpi: Ignoring file entry whose name is not a valid add-on ID:
 C:\Users\Salma.n\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous38301webdriver-profile\extensions\webdriver-staging

*** LOG addons.xpi: checkForChanges

*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Opening XPI database 
C:\Users\Salma.n\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous38301webdriver-profile\extensions.json

*** LOG addons.xpi: New add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com installed in app-profile

*** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled

*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Make addon app-profile:fxdriver@googlecode.com visible

*** LOG DeferredSave/extensions.json: Save changes

*** LOG DeferredSave/extensions.json: Save changes

*** LOG addons.xpi: New add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} installed in app-global

*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Make addon app-global:{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} visible

*** LOG DeferredSave/extensions.json: Save changes

*** LOG DeferredSave/extensions.json: Save changes

*** LOG addons.xpi: Updating database with changes to installed add-ons

*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Updating add-on states

*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Writing add-ons list

*** LOG DeferredSave/extensions.json: Starting timer

*** LOG DeferredSave/extensions.json: Starting write

*** LOG DeferredSave/extensions.json: Write succeeded

*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 15

*** LOG addons.manager: shutdown

*** LOG addons.xpi: shutdown

*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: shutdown

*** LOG addons.xpi: Notifying XPI shutdown observers

*** LOG addons.manager: Async provider shutdown done

*** LOG addons.xpi: startup

*** LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-local

*** LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share

*** LOG addons.xpi: Ignoring file entry whose name is not a valid add-on ID:
```

Comment: I downgrade firefox back to firefox 25 . Now its working.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same error on Win7, upgrading to 2.39 worked for me

```
<seleniumVersion>2.39.0</seleniumVersion>
```

I would just ensure that 2.39.0 version is actually being used (check the logs), maybe a maven clean install is required?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem (also win 7), for me upgrading to selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0 worked fine though.

Maybe you forgot to import the new jar in your project? Just looking at the obvious stupid mistakes someone can make...

Comment: I added selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0 jar file too. but still it dint work for me.

Comment: If he's just using FF Driver, not RemoteWebdriver, he doesn't need server-standalone. I had the same issue - it was working fine with FF 26 and WebDriver 2.38.0 until it suddenly stopped working. Upgrading to 2.39.0 fixed the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Incorrect verion of xml-api through Maven dependency seems to prevent Firefox from starting (no error message either). In my case, hibernate-entity-manager-4.3.8 -> dom4j-1.6.1 -> xml-api-1.0.b2 caused the issue. Excluding it as below lets me use xml-api-1.4.01 from xercesImpl-2.11 dependency chain. I used Firefox version 36.0.4 and WebDriver 2.45.0.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```